# pandas dataframe: index is DatetimeIndex and 4 columns. Some NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming my dataframe df is sorted,

1. how do I find the dates for which all 4 columns are NA?
       the frame is expected to be such that all all-NA rows have dates earlier than the rest of the frame.
2. Drop all the rows for such dates that are earlier than everything else
3. Detect if any rows have at least of NA later in the frame?

E.g. frame:

```
            A   B   C
1977-1-1    NA  NA  NA
1977-1-2    NA   NA  NA
...
1978-1-1    10.5  5.5 6.5
...
2014-1-1    10.2  50.0  9.0
```

1. remove all all-NA rows that are before the first non-all-NA row (1978-1-1)
2. then, there shouldn't be any all-NA rows after 1978-1-1. if there are, report them.
   will be considered for removal after some processing
3. then, report also any rows that have at least a NA. will be considered differently

Comment: [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) takes a `thresh` param to specify the number of non-Na values, also `axis=1` specifies a row, can you post input data and code and expected output. There could be a million ways to answer your question at present

Comment: I have added a example. is axis=1 or 0 with dropna()? I want to remove rows only, never columns.

Comment: `axis=0` drops rows, `axis=1` will drop columns, sorry the meaning of axis changes depending the on the operation

Comment: ok, is there a way to find the days where all cols are NA? How do I do it with isnull()?

Comment: `pd.isnull(df)` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. remove all all-NA rows that are before the first non-all-NA row.

   ```
   frame = frame[frame.index >= frame[(~frame.A.isnull()) & (~frame.B.isnull()) & (~frame.C.isnull())].head(1).index]
   ```
2. report all-NA rows after 1978-1-1

   ```
   allNA = frame[(frame.A.isnull()) & (frame.B.isnull()) & (frame.C.isnull())]
   ```

   or

   ```
   allNA = frame[frame.T.isnull().all()]
   ```
3. report also any rows that have at least a NA

   ```
   anyNA = frame[(frame.A.isnull()) | (frame.B.isnull()) | (frame.C.isnull())]
   ```

   or

   ```
   anyNA = frame[frame.T.isnull().any()]
   ```

Comment: NaN, so I assume the change would be to use isnull(frame.A) ?

Comment: Edited for NaN values